# Simulate right click

Tags: java, swing, click, mouse, right-click

I am wondering how to make my Java program simulate a right click. So imagine your mouse cannot right click anymore. How do I make Java simulate the right click? Im planning to have a button that u press on a JFrame that simulates the right click after x seconds. Thanks and please try to include some code and not just links

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [`java.awt.Robot`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) api was designed for exactly this. It has lots of goodies in it!

Specifically in this case, [mousePress](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#mousePress%28int%29) and [mouseRelease](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#mouseRelease%28int%29).

P.S. Yes I realize they're just links. But in all honesty, learning to read API docs and make code from them effectively is a skill every developer needs!

Comment: +1, for only providing the links. Totally agree with the comment, I wish more people did.

Comment: Well it boils down to the whole "give a man a fish, teach a man to fish" thing. Although, some people weren't meant to fish.

Comment: LOL fine...everyone in stack overflow is the same. Im just a teenager in high school taking hard ap courses i already have enough to cram into my head it wud be nice if the code was handed to me but oh well. at least ive been given a pointer. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> Im planning to have a button that u press on a jframe that simulates the right click after x seconds

```
button.doClick();
```

Comment: This is nice, and much lighter weight than the robot method. You'd have to wrap it in some kind of (hopefully asynchronous, non busy) delay mechanism to get the "x number of seconds" requirement.

Comment: It may not be what you want, it actually does the click of the button. I thought your where trying to click a button from within your code.

Answer (score 2):

Windows?

Control Panel | Ease of Access | Make the mouse easier to use | Control the mouse with the keyboard

---

As an aside.  A mouse is usually less that $10.  If your time is worth $20 an hour, you'd have to finish the code within 30 minutes to make it cheaper than buying a new mouse.  This project seems a 'false economy'.